# What does this php syntax mean "$string{0}"

Tags: php, syntax

I came across `$string{0}` here: https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/blob/6c15cef0b1b2cb4c438e526c78d805b69a733f9d/phpMQTT.php#L154

I'm struggling to understand the `{0}` part of it. Does it mean the last character, the first character, the last digit in binary representation, the first digit in binary representation?

Is it still compatible with PHP 7.1?

Comment: So, __what__ is the problem with creating a sample script and see how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$string{0}` is similar to `$string[0]`, which will print the character at *0th* index in `$string` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is [string access and modification by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). Since PHP 5.5 it also works with string literals.

Comment: 5.5 just introduced character access to a string *literal*, e.g. `"foo"[0]`. I think string variables have worked since, well, forever.

Comment: @iainn You're right, I didn't read the documentation careful enough on the first time. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset as in $str{42}

> <s>However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 6. Use square brackets
>   instead.</s>

Looks like the German manual needs an update; thx to iainn for pointing it out!

[source](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I think the German manual might need an update there, since PHP 6 isn't a thing. Both square and curly brackets are valid.

Comment: hmm, good catch